# Find checkbox column in gridview OnCheckedChange event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

I have few gridview columns with `checkboxes control` that has an `autopostback='true'` to update a db.

[image]

When i check one of the checkboxes the entire row gets updated which makes me frustrated.

I'm trying to find the `checkbox control` of the column **not** the whole gridview

I know that `Mycheckbox.checked` will always be true because it looks at the "checked values for all" however i want it only to look in the column specified

Is it possible to do something like `Checkbox MyCheckbox = findcontrol(*MyColumn*)`......

```
protected void myCheckBox_OnCheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)myCheckBox.NamingContainer;
    bool status = myCheckBox.Checked;   
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_tblPlanningChecked", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlanningID", row.Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThisWeekMinus2", myCheckBox.Checked);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThisWeekMinus1", myCheckBox.Checked);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThisWeek", myCheckBox.Checked);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThisWeekPlus1", myCheckBox.Checked);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThisWeekPlus2", myCheckBox.Checked);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThisWeekMinus3", myCheckBox.Checked);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThisWeekMinus4", myCheckBox.Checked);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have read your question a few times but I still don't get what you are trying to do. So you have `column1` and want to get all the `CheckBox`es that are `Checked == true` ?

Comment: This is just utterly confusing. In your picture are 7 columns and each column has like 10 `Checkboxes`.

Comment: What the heck does that mean: `iim trying to find out how i can use "findcontrol" of a column insted of using myCheckBox as the only checkbox sender` ? So you want to find a control? Please just answer with `Yes` or `No`, in order to keep it simple. Furthermore you dont want to use each comboBox`s sender in its event as a converted `ComboBox` event, what else do you want to use then? What is your goal in total?

Comment: Ok so let's imagine we are in `Column` column1. Now you want to get all the `CheckBoxes` in column1 that are checked right? `Yes` or `No`?

Comment: But now you talk about a (implifies *one* this in this example) column. But this one column has quite a few CheckBoxes. So how do you imagine just getting true/false when there can be different CheckBoxes with either checked/unckecked?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try below code

```
foreach (GridViewRow grow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chkStat = grow.FindControl("chkStatus") as CheckBox;
    int index = grow.RowIndex;
    if (chkStat.Checked)
    {
        //Write some code if checkbox is checked
    }
    else
    {
        //Write some code if checkbox is not checked
    }
}
```

Comment: I tweeked your code a bit but this line: CheckBox chkStat = grow.FindControl("chkStatus") as CheckBox; was the main line i was after.